# please let me know why my code didn't work well ?(appscript and html files)

Tags: google-apps-script

please let me know why my code didn't work well ?(appscript and html files) ,  have google spread sheet an access to it , but the code always go to els condition not to if ... 
i want when i login check first if found the mail on spreadsheet goto home page if else stay on the login page

script code

```
function doGet(e) {
  var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index'); 
  return template.evaluate();
  var p = e.parameter;
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1EaBfdWqgc927-Syt-H7DwtN7JyYE_VqMBsQs_hnthRg');
  var data = sheet.getSheetByName('Teacher Contact Information').getDataRange().getValues();
  var iqraEmail= p.email;

   for (i in data) {
    if (data[i][5] == p && iqraEmail){
      Logger.log(iqraEmail);
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Home').setTitle("Syllabus");

    }

      else 
 {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setTitle("Login");
 }
       break;

 }

}
```

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <base target="_top">


  </head>
  <body style="background-image:url('http://drive.google.com/uc?export=view&amp;id=1N8D4M91tqNUgKuEId1p0OKaY1sUpRhrd')">


  <form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxCaNjVg0x-uFT5dD0xH5YgTMADHoMAraRIhna2XWc1-mgKsSI/exec" class="mx-5 mt-5">

          <center>
        <img class="" style="margin: 8rem 1rem 1rem !important" src="https://iqranetwork.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/logo_v2.png" />

        <h2>
          <strong>IQRA Syllabus</strong>
        </h2>


        </center>





        <div class="form-row">


            <div class="form-group col-md-4"></div>
        <div class="form-group col-md-4">

            <label style="text-align: center" for=""><span class="required"></span><strong>IQRA Email :</strong> </label>
            <input class="form-control" type="email" placeholder="---" name="email" id="email" required>

        </div>



        </div>


        <input type="hidden" name="" id="" value="">

        <div style="text-align: center">

         <button type="submit" id="submit" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="google.script.host.close()"> Login </button>

          </div>

    </form>

  <!-- ==================================================== Form End =================================== -->


  </body>
</html>
```

home.html

````
<html>
 <head>
   <base target="_top">
 </head>
 <body>
  <form action="https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbxCaNjVg0x-uFT5dD0xH5YgTMADHoMAraRIhna2XWc1-mgKsSI/exec" class="mx-5 mt-5">
   Hello
   </form>
 </body>
</html>  ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Although I don't get to see your sheet and I am unable to set up appscript now, let me see if I can help from my head. At first, I am assuming that the only wrong portion is the script code. Thus, try this first:

```
function doGet(e) {
    var template = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile('Index'); 
    return template.evaluate();
}

function doPost(e){
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('1EaBfdWqgc927-Syt-H7DwtN7JyYE_VqMBsQs_hnthRg');
    var data = sheet.getSheetByName('Teacher Contact Information').getDataRange().getValues();
    var iqraEmail= e.parameter.email;
    
    for (i in data) {
        if (data[i][5] == iqraEmail){
        Logger.log(iqraEmail);
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Home').setTitle("Syllabus");
        }
    }

    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index').setTitle("Login");
}
```